# How can i make laravel routes accessible from phpdesktop chrome?

Tags: laravel, phpdesktop

I have a laravel 6 application that I want to put into setup form. so i found phpdesktop chrome and copy my app content to phpdesktop www folder. When I start the application with the setup, it shows me the home page, but when I click on a button to access my login page, I receive this error: Error 404: Not Found
File not found.
What can I do to make the routes accessible via the desktop application?
any help would be appreciated. thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to put `/index.php` at line `"404_handler"`:

```
 "web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 62412],
    "www_directory": "www/public",
    "index_files": ["index.html", "index.php"],
    "cgi_interpreter": "php/php-cgi.exe",
    "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
    "cgi_temp_dir": "",
    "404_handler": "/index.php",
    "hide_files": []
},
```